# How to create molecule image similar with molconvert using RDKit

Tags: cheminformatics

I have the following molecule in SMILE format (saved as `my_molecule.smi`):

```
[H]N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC1=CNC2=C1C=CC=C2)C(O)=O
```

I created an image using ChemAxon Marvin's [**molconvert**](https://docs.chemaxon.com/display/docs/molconvert.md) command:

```
MarvinSuite/bin/molconvert "jpeg:w800:h800" my_molecule.smi -o mol.jpg
```

It produces the following image:

[image]

Then I use [RDKit](https://www.rdkit.org), with the following code:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('[H]N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC1=CNC2=C1C=CC=C2)C(O)=O')
m
```

I get this image:

[image]

Notice that it is circular, and missing an H3C.
With RDKit, how can I create the identical image with the one made by `molconvert`?
i.e. straight format and H3C included.

Python code can be tried in [**my Google Colab**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AJy1YcIpSvr2x5s-LFHisKU4LhI0cOEW?usp=sharing).

Comment: I'm not sure why you care about a linear format. Is there actually a reason you want that?

Comment: If you happen to speak JavaScript, [SmilesDrawer](https://github.com/reymond-group/smilesDrawer) might be an option for you, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not going to get something identical. Different toolkits use different code to do 2D molecule layout. Generally the current RDKit code (which uses the CoordGen library) tends to prefer geometries closer to square, which is useful when drawing a bunch of molecules in a grid.

In short, I don't think there's anything you can do if you prefer an extended form and want RDKit to generate that.

Adding explicit methyl groups is pretty easy with recent RDKit (2020.03 and later), which adds [new drawing options](http://rdkit.blogspot.com/2020/04/new-drawing-options-in-202003-release.html), e.g.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import rdMolDraw2D
from rdkit.Chem import rdDepictor
rdDepictor.SetPreferCoordGen(True)
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from IPython.display import SVG

m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('[H]N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC1=CNC2=C1C=CC=C2)C(O)=O')

d2d = rdMolDraw2D.MolDraw2DSVG(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().explicitMethyl =True
d2d.DrawMolecule(m)
d2d.FinishDrawing()
SVG(d2d.GetDrawingText())
```

The options are documented for the [rdMolDraw2D module](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.Draw.rdMolDraw2D.html)